# resume a file using curl or wget?

Tags: file-transfer, http

I am unsure why but there's one file on a server which chokes every time when it gets to 10mb. The file reported is 16mb. Can I use wget or curl to get and resume the file? When I used Firefox to resume I got some error about source but I know the files on the server are streamed and have jump to the middle of a file so I should be able to resume.

Maybe I can use another tool, any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

`wget` has `-c`, which will attempt to continue the download at its current point based on the size of the file downloaded thus far.